# ¿Cómo eliminar un registro de firestore?

Tags: firebase, angular

Dentro de Firestore tengo una colección llamada `galeria-img`, la cual contiene objetos con un nombre y una url.

```
/
  galeria-img
    kja123oiu1kja123oiu1masdkjhasd
      nombre: 'foto1.jpg'
      url: 'https://XXXXXXX.com/foto1.jpg'
    912323oiu1kja123oiu1masdkjjs92
      nombre: 'foto2.jpg'
      url: 'https://XXXXXXX.com/foto2.jpg'
    kj2323oiu1kja123oiu1masdkjjeiw
      nombre: 'foto3.jpg'
      url: 'https://XXXXXXX.com/foto3.jpg'
```

Y quiero, por ejemplo, eliminar el objeto `912323oiu1kja123oiu1masdkjjs92` que corresponde a la `foto2.jpg`.

Siguiendo la [documentación de Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data?hl=es-419) tengo lo siguiente:

```
private eliminarImagenDB( imagen: any ) {
  let ruta: string = 'galeria-img';
  this.db.collection(ruta).doc(imagen).delete().then( () => {
    console.log(imagen.nombre, ' borrada de la base de datos');
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Error al eliminar ', imagen.nombre);
  });
}
```

Pero la consola me arroja un error en `doc(imagen)`, dice que se espera un argumento de tipo string. Intenté corregirlo con `doc(imagen.nombre)`, el cual es de tipo string; pero esto no funciona.

¿Saben cuál es la manera correcta de eliminar registros de Firebase con los datos que tengo almacenados?

Answer (score 1):

Tuve que hacer varias cosas para poder lograr esto.

Primero en mi componente.ts importe lo siguiente:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

Después tuve que crear las interfaces de los datos:

```
export interface Imagen { name: string; url: string; }
export interface ImagenID extends Imagen { id: string; }
```

Y utilizar esas interfaces en mi constructor:

```
private imagenCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Imagen>;
imagenes: Observable<Imagen[]>;

constructor(
  private router:Router,
  private _registroImg: SubirImagenGaleriaService,
  private afs: AngularFirestore
) {
    this.imagenCollection = afs.collection<Imagen>('carpeta-de-imagenes');
    this.imagenes = this.imagenCollection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Imagen;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
  });
}
```

Donde la línea `this.imagenes = this.imagenCollection.snapshotChanges().map` se encarga de obtener el ID del documento. Este ID es generado automáticamente por Firebase cada que se agrega un documento.

Después en mi servicio declaro el siguiente método:

```
private eliminarImagenDB( imagen: string ) {
  let ruta: string = 'carpeta-de-imagenes';
  this.db.collection(ruta).doc(imagen).delete().then( function() {
    //console.log(imagen, ' eliminada');
  }).catch(function(error) {
    //console.error('Error eliminando ', error);
  });
}
```

Y le mando como parámetro el id:

```
this.eliminarImagenDB(imagen.id);
```

Para llegar a esta solución me base del [siguiente ejemplo de angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/7eb3e51022c7381dfc94ffb9e12555065f060639/docs/firestore/collections.md#example).

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema es que le estas pasando el objeto imagen a la función, pero lo que necesitas pasar es el id del objeto almacenado en la colección.

```js
this.eliminarImagen("912323oiu1kja123oiu1masdkjjs92");

private eliminarImagenDB( imagen: any ) {
  let ruta: string = 'galeria-img';
  this.db.collection(ruta).doc(imagen).delete().then( () => {
    console.log(imagen.nombre, ' borrada de la base de datos');
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Error al eliminar ', imagen.nombre);
  });
}
```